# Polynomial rings and Gauss lemma

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt {-11}]$ and $F = Quot(R) = \mathbb{Q}$$[\sqrt {-11}] = \{m+n\sqrt{-11}:m,n \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

I have to show for Gauss Lemma that the domain of $R$ is not a unique factorization domain.

**My attempt:**

I used the polynomial $x^2-x+3$ and showed is irreducible in $R[x]$ but reducible in $F[x]$, Can I used for show the Gauss lemma?

Comment: Hint: consider $(1 + \sqrt{-11})(1 - \sqrt{-11}) = 12 = 2^2 3$.

Comment: You are already pretty much done: By the Gauss lemma if a non-constant polynomial $f$ is irreducible over a UFD $R$ then it is also irreducible over the fraction field of $R$. You found a polynomial that violates this condition so your ring is not a UFD.